# iperf UDP server start error, bind failed: Operation not permitted

Tags: windows, sockets, udp, iperf

*OS : Windows 8, 
Tool : Jperf, 
internal Tool : iperf*

i want to start UDP Server listener.

Command Used:-

### iperf -s -u -P 0 -i 1 -p 5001 -l 1470 -f k -t 10

Server listening on UDP port 5001

Receiving 1470 byte datagrams

UDP buffer size: 64.0 KByte (default)

Error as follows :-

**bind failed: Operation not permitted**

recvfrom failed: Invalid argument

Comments :-

1)  My Windows Firewall is OFF

2) Antivirus is OFF

Any Registory changes required here to access windows UDP ports ?
Any Idea ?

Comment: After port number 6007,6008,6009... UDP port connection is working for me. Problem solved, but don't have any technical reason for this with me that "why this is not connecting for less than port number 6006 ?".

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, but only after I installed an altogether different application on the same machine where I had successfully run iperf -s -u previously. When I assigned another port for iperf to use such as 5555 or 6007 the iperf server no longer gave a bind error and presented the stats after the transfer as expected.

I suspect the reason for this is that another program that I installed grabbed the UDP port or range of ports for itself. This would be easy for a program to do if iperf is running in user-mode instead of daemon mode. On the other hand some programs are still particular about running on specific ports, so in case of a conflict you may still have to assign specific port usage.